# How to build PythonQt in ubutnu

Tags: c++, qt, pythonqt

I want to embed the `python` script in my `c++ Qt` application, By searching on the net I found that `PythonQt` is exactly what I am looking for but when I went to it's `github repo` there is build description given for windows system but not for `ubuntu` system so after cloning the `repo` if I include it's `src` in my `Qt .pro` file it gives me output that
`Python.h not found`, I think the reason is that I didn't build it in my system. Is there anyone who could tell me that how to build `PythonQt` in ubuntu. The link for their `repo` is this: https://github.com/MeVisLab/pythonqt

If this didn't work you can also suggest me some other thing which will help me to embed `python` scripts into my `Qt c++` application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First clone the `repo` by using the following command
`https://github.com/MeVisLab/pythonqt.git`
After that `cd` into the clone folder and execute the below command to `build` it into your system.

```
qmake
```

This command will generate the `MakeFile` into your current directory run the following command to completely build the `PythonQt` in your system.

```
sudo make all
sudo make install
```

While executing those commands if you get the following error

```
fatal error: 'private/qmetaobjectbuilder_p.h'
```

Run the below command to solve this

```
sudo apt install qtbase5-private-dev
```